# create a button in ribbon for update a entity using a plugin in crm 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I create a solution in Dynamic CRM 2011 for sending SMS.

in my solution i have 2 entity,the first one for sending SMS and the second one for save Send result.

I create plugin for second entity, plugin connect to web service and check the result of sending and update the entity, so the steps for update sending statue should be like below:

1- User select one or more entity and press a custom button in ribbon

2- CRM run my plugin and connect to web service and update the result field

so i create the plug in and create the button but i don't know how to run plugin(C# Code) when button hase been pressed.

if any one know this or have better solution for update SMS result, please tell me.

note: i register a Update step  and a pre Image for plugin.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 (no javascript or custom button):**

Create a `Check Send Status` checkbox on the `SMS` entity. Move your plugin from the `Send result` entity to the `Update` of the `SMS` entity, and make it fire when `Check Send Status` is set to true. The plugin can now check the send status for the `SMS` and create the `Send result` entity with the appropriate result.

Your users can then use the multi-edit button. They can highlight multiple `SMS` records, click Edit and then set `Check Send Status` to true, which will fire your plugin.

**Option 2 (custom javascript):**

Write a javascript method for your button that will use the `SelectedControlSelectedItemIds` parameter. See here for more information: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79f959ac-0846-472f-bff1-4f5afe692a56/getting-selected-records-guids-in-crm-2011?forum=crm

Your javascript method needs to loop through those IDs and then create the `Send result` record, which should fire your existing plugin (assuming it is on `Create`).

Comment: what you mean by make it fire when check send status is set to true? i mean how can i fire a plugin when user click on a check box. in SMS entity plugin ,when user are sending sms, entity result are creating, but my problem is the web SMS provider web service dose not have a correct real time answer , so i want to user can check result later by peressing a button.

Comment: The user would check the checkbox and then save the record. Your plugin would fire on Update of the SMS entity, and you would configure it to only fire on update of the "Check Send Status" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly call a plugin from a ribbon button (indirectly you could update the record which triggers the plugin)

The javascript options above are great options, but if you would like to work within managed code:

Another option could be to connect the ribbon button to a workflow to calls a custom workflow activity that preforms whatever logic you need to preform.  This will prevent you from having to trigger a plugin and instead just call on on-demand workflow.

Let me know if you need any assistance with how to do that.

Comment: thanks . you are correct. i use a data field for for fire update plugin